# Why is the Karma configuration file exclude option is not working?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I have two spec files in my sample Angular app. The spec files names are 
`src/app/app.component.spec.ts` & `src/app/app.component-two.spec.ts`. I want to run only the tests in file `src/app/app.component.spec.ts`. So, I added the other file as exclude in the `karma.conf.js` file (pasted below), still the tests mentioned in the exclude option are being executed.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    exclude: [
      'src/app/app.component-two.spec.ts'
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: what is your setup for testing? angular-cli? webpack? systemjs? how do you transpile `ts` to `js`?

Comment: Angular CLI, internally it uses webpack. Transpiling seems to be via Babel

Comment: yes, karma for some reason ignores the `exludes`, maybe create an issue in cli and link it here. meanwhile, you can also use `tsconfig.spec.json` to exclude the files. see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exclude the file in the `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": { ... },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "app/app.component-two.spec.ts"    <------------------
  ]
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. but even after i exclude the files in tsconfig.spec.json it is not excluded for test execution.  is anything am missing

Comment: @zulu, can you create a separate question?

Comment: raise new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637506/how-to-exclude-folder-components-for-unit-testing-in-angular-4-using-karma-con

Comment: Did not work for me: _Module build failed: Error: <file>.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property._, followed by a script error.

Comment: @bgerth, it's likely things have changed since

Comment: This solution does not work for angular 6 and 7. I have tried it and got same error as @bgerth.

Comment: @Felix, yeah, there's been a lot of updates since the answer

Comment: The right answer is under @zulu's link. In an Angular project, test files are actually selected in `src/test.ts`, not in `karma.conf.js`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `src/test.ts`

```
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

declare const require: {
  context(
    path: string,
    deep?: boolean,
    filter?: RegExp
  ): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

const excludedSpecs = ['./app/app.component-two.spec.ts'];

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

// And load the modules.
context
  .keys()
  .filter(file => excludedSpecs.includes(file) === false)
  .forEach(context);
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations to complete your answer. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer