# How to exclude Folder (components) for unit testing in Angular 4 using Karma config?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using angular cli version 1.4.5 and below is the karma.conf.ts file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
  basePath: '',
  exclude: [
     "src/app/components/panel/panel.component.spec.ts",
     "src/app/components/accordion/accordion.component.spec.ts"
   ],
   frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
   plugins: [
     require('karma-jasmine'),
     require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
     require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
     require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
     require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
   ],
   client:{
     clearContext: false 
   },
   coverageIstanbulReporter: {
     reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
     fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
   },
   angularCli: {
     environment: 'dev'
   },
   reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
   port: 9876,
   colors: true,
   logLevel: config.DEBUG,
   autoWatch: true,
   browsers: ['Chrome'],
   singleRun: false
 });
};
```

and I even added the exclude in the tsconfig.spec.json file to exclude to pick those files for test.

```
{
 .....,
 "include": [
 "**/*.spec.ts",
 "**/*.d.ts"
 ],
 "exclude": [
     "app/components/panel/panel.component.spec.ts",
     "app/components/accordion/accordion.component.spec.ts"
 ]
}
```

is that am missing something to add for exclusion ?

Answer (score 6):

Change the config in the `src/test.ts`.

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9026#issuecomment-354475734

Comment: Works for Angular 7 too.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated February 2024**

For Angular-CLI 10 & latest, there is really no need to exclude them in your `karma.conf.js` as that won't work without further re-configurations.

Easiest way is to navigate to your `angular.json` which contains the configurations. If it's not there already, add `codeCoverageExclude:`  array & include the files & folders to be excluded during karma build on `ng test`.

To do so, add `codeCoverageExclude` property which accepts an array of files to be excluded from code coverage as below.

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    ...
    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
    ...
    "codeCoverageExclude": [
       "src/app/components/panel/**",
       "src/components/accordion/**",
       "src/app/*.ts"
     ],
```

To examine the result, run `ng test --code-coverage` and navigate to the newly created `coverage` folder of your app root directory and doudle-click to open the `index.html` file & see the pdf report in your browser.

PS: For smooth testing, Angular's Karma & Jasmine are configured by default to expect [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) installed in your machine for tests to complete.

- Happy testing & May Code be with you!