# angular tsconfig json Exclude not working when i use "**/*.spec.ts" pattern

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to exclude spec files inside this path "projects/sci-core/src/**/*".

I have exclude block with following config

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

The above config excluding the spec files inside the src folder(inside the root folder). but not excluding the under projects/sci-core/src folder.
below is my include block

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "projects/studio-widgets/**/*",
    "!projects/sci-core/src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "projects/sci-core/src/**/*"
  ],
```

I have tried with the below approach also.

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
"projects/sci-core/src/**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637506/how-to-exclude-folder-components-for-unit-testing-in-angular-4-using-karma-con

Comment: @HsuanLee we are using jest unit testing's. the above one which you provided was using karma

Answer (score 0):

The `tsconfig` file is only for the ts-compiler, you can't use it to exclude spec files. You should filter your spec files in the test file.

**test.ts**

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// Filter specify file
const specFiles = context.keys().filter((path: string) => !path.includes('sci-core'));
// And load the modules.
specFiles.map(context);
```

Comment: made above changes Still we are getting below `error.projects/sci-core/src/lib/layout/sci-footer/sci-footer.component.spec.ts(33,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.`