# angular unit test to skip for components which has errors

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a project folder which has lot of error, since we have update the ui to new version we are failing with old test cases. I want to run a particular folder which has ten components alone and want to skip other folders since we are facing lot of issue.

I have tried fdescribe, xdescribe and tried to changing the test.ts file -> require.context path. Then also issue still exists for all the folders.

Is there is a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore spec files in your `tsconfig.spec.json`

Check out [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545680/max-koretskyi) answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358556/5485675

Answer (score 0):

This are the analysis which i have found to skip components which has errors, and to run the specific components.

1. To run a single component we can modify in test.ts file. you can modify a context variable like this

   const context = require.context('./', true, /**your-component-to-run**.spec.ts$/);
2. To run a folder of components, you can modify the contest variable like below

   const context = require.context('./**your-path-to-folder**', true, /.spec.ts$/);
3. To skip the lot of folders which you don't want to run, can be achieved by modifying in the tsconfig.spec.json

   exclude: [
               your-folder-path-1/****,
               your-folder-path-2/****,
               your-folder-path-n/****,
              ]

you can add the exclude array after the include array.

Above things will work if you face any issues with test cases and you want to avoid that particular file or folder or bunch of folders.

**You will be able run the components and files like 1 and 2 method after you excluded the components which has errors in tsconfig.spec.json**

If you don't face any issues , want to run only the specific component . You will be able to run the component by using fdescribe and fit methods.